# ParametricPlot returns empty output

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I'm trying to generate the phase portrait for this differential equation equation:

$(1+my^2)(d^2y/dx^2)+my(dy/dx)^2+y+1.1y^3$

Where y[0] = 6, dy/dx = 0; m = 0.55. The plot is for x between 0 and 15 (inclusive) so I tried the following. The code doesn't generate any error but there is also no plot as you can see below. Can someone help me with this?

[image: image of code]

Comment: Sorry the website was giving me problems with typing the code

Comment: I think there’s some misunderstanding on syntax. Try something like `Plot[soln[0.55][t], {t, 0, 15}]` instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
soln = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(1 + m y[x])^2 y''[x] + 
    m  y[x] (y'[x])^2 + y[x] + 1.1 (y[x])^3 == 0, y[0] == 6,  y'[0] == 0},
  y, {x, 0, 15}, {m}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[{t, soln[m][t]}, {m, 0, 2, .5}]], {t, 0, 15}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {-10, 10}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "y[m][t]"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"m = ", m}], {m, 0, 2, .5}]]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[{soln[m]@t, soln[m]'@t}, {m, 0, 2, .5}]], {t, 0, 15}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-30, 30}}, 
 AxesLabel -> { "y[m][t]", "y[m]'[t]"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"m = ", m}], {m, 0, 3, .5}]]
```

[image]

To plot `y[m][t]` vs `y[m]'[t]` it is more convenient to change the second argument of `ParametricNDSolveValue` to `{y, y'}` to get a *pair* of parametric functions (for `y` and `y'`, respectively):

```
soln2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{(1 + m y[x])^2 y''[x] + 
      m  y[x] (y'[x])^2 + y[x] + 1.1 (y[x])^3 == 0, y[0] == 6,  y'[0] == 0},
   {y, y'}, {x, 0, 15}, {m}];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[Through @ soln2[m] @ t, {m, 0, 2, .5}]], {t, 0, 15}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-30, 30}}, 
 AxesLabel -> { "y[m][t]", "y[m]'[t]"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"m = ", m}], {m, 0, 2, .5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: the last graph is the output I need but it needs to be symmetrical (left side should like the right side of what you have here) any idead how I can fix this? My desired m values are 0.55,1.15,3.85, 11.35

Comment: Try pl1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[Table[Through@soln2[m]@t, {m, 0, 2, .5}]], {t, 0, 15}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-30, 30}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"y[m][t]", "y[m]'[t]"}, 
   PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"m = ", m}], {m, 0, 2, .5}]];

pl2 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate[
    Table[(Through@soln2[m]@t) /. {a_[t], b_[t]} -> {-a[t], b[t]}, {m,
       0, 2, .5}]], {t, 0, 15}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-30, 30}}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"y[m][t]", "y[m]'[t]"}, 
   PlotLegends -> Table[Row[{"m = ", m}], {m, 0, 2, .5}]];

Show[pl1, pl2]

Comment: the graph looks good thanks. If I want those specific values of m instead of setting an increment like your code should i do {m, 1,{0.55,1.15,3.85, 11.35}}?

Comment: @Ali, you  should use `{m, {0.55,1.15,3.85, 11.35}}`.